# Is it possible to add arbitrary HTML attributes to a field by extending a generic ListView?

Tags: django, django-views

I am using a generic.ListView to display a model. I want to display one field of the modelview with bold or italics or a different colour (or whatever) depending on the value of another field, but I can't figure out how to add an html id (or css class or whatever attribute is required) to a field in a generic.ListView.

here is the model:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    QUESTION_TYPES = (
       (0,'Header'),
       (1,'Sub-Header'),
       (2,'Blurb'),
       (3,'Standard Question'),
       (4,'Multiple-Choice Question'),
       (5,'Standard Sub-Question'),
       (6,'Multiple-Choice Sub-Question')
    )
    name = models.CharField('Question', max_length=255, unique=False)
    survey = models.ForeignKey(Survey)
    question_type = models.IntegerField(default=3,choices=QUESTION_TYPES)
    validation = models.ForeignKey(Validation)
    sort_order = models.FloatField()
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    show = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

and here is the view:

```
class QuestionIndex(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'questions/index.html'
    context_object_name = "questions_list"

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Question.objects.order_by('sort_order')
```

I want to add some sort of `(attrs={'id':'blurb'})` type thing to the model.name, row by row depending on the value of model.question_type for that row. Thus each row of model.name could potentially have a different html id when it displays. 'Blurb' rows might have a different font size and might be italic, for instance, determined by the id in the template's css.

I want to do it in the view rather than in the template if possible, based on my understanding that templates should be as light as can be.

Is it possible? I have searched the docs and Googled it and I can't find it.

How do I do it?

thanks in advance

John

PS As you can tell I am new to Django, and would appreciate any help!

PPS I don't absolutely have to use generic model views, but I'm very biased towards using them as a starting point for the sake of code minimisation.

Comment: That should go into the template, not the view. The template is for rendering HTML and display logic. The view is for fetching and saving data, and applying business logic. Also, no real reason to keep the templates as "light as you can", they typically are the "messiest" part of the operation.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Because it's incredibly easy to add to the template, I must say. `<td class='question_{{item.question_type}}'>`   I was thinking it should go in the view.